# Is it possible to do feature selection within the Keras deep learning framework?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, keras

I know most people perform feature selection running RFE on a linear regression model, for example, BEFORE training the model with Keras.

However is it possible to do it within the training procedure of the deep neural network? If so how? Are there any downsides to it?

Comment: One popular way to do variable selection that transfer immediately to gradient based learning with Keras is sparsifying penalties, like the $\ell_1$ penalty ("lasso regression"). Something kinda sorta like what's proposed here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00485.pdf